# trying to publish an array of words in rospy using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ros

I am trying to create a subscriber which accepts a word (meaning a string of characters) and then collects those words into an array and then publish the array of these words.

I am trying to use numpy for this. The length of my array always has to be 3 with the latest word at the end. This way I wil have two previous words with the latest word at the end of the array.

This is the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg
import numpy
#added

def callback(data):
    global c
    pub = rospy.Publisher('tag_history',numpy_msg(String))

c.append(str(data.data))
if len(c)>3:
   c=c[1:4]    
d=numpy.array(c,dtype=numpy.str)
print c
pub.publish(d)
rospy.sleep(0.5)



def listener():

   rospy.init_node('tag_history', anonymous=True)

   rospy.Subscriber("DA_tags", String, callback)
   rospy.spin()


 if __name__ == '__main__':

 global c
 c=[]
 listener()
```

When I run this code, this is the error i get :

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1401656539.688481] bad callback: <function callback at 0x2456758>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 682, in          _invoke_callback
cb(msg)
File "./tag_history.py", line 17, in callback
pub.publish(d)
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 802, in publish
raise ROSSerializationException(str(e))
ROSSerializationException: field data must be of type str
```

What does this error "field data must be of type str" mean? How do I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that at line 17 you are passing a numpy array to `pub.publish`, but it requires a string.

Answer (score 0):

THanks for pointing it out RodrigoOlma. I fixed my problwm by creating a custom msg in ros which is an array of strings. I declared it like this string[] data and named the data type StringArray. I changed my code to this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from beginner_tutorials.msg import StringArray


def callback(data):
    global c
    str=StringArray()
    pub = rospy.Publisher('tag_history',StringArray)
    c.append(data.data)
    if len(c)>3:
       c=c[1:4]    
    str.data=c
    print str
    pub.publish(str)

def listener():

     rospy.init_node('tag_history', anonymous=True)

     rospy.Subscriber("DA_tags", String, callback)
     rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':

     global c
     c=[]
     listener()
```